# Changing typesetting if frame subtitle exists

Tags: beamer, conditionals, frame-title

I wanted to change the typesetting of my frame title and frame subtitle in Beamer, and ended up using the following code:

```
  \begin{center}
    {\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\insertframetitle}
    \\[0.8ex]
    \fontsize{10}{11}\color{black!40}\selectfont\sffamily\insertframesubtitle
  \end{center}
}
```

This typesets the frame title, adds a space, and then typesets the frame subtitle.

However, some of my slides have no framesubtitle. In this case, I still get the extra space, which is a bit annoying. Is there. a way to have something like "if frame subtitle exists" then add the space and frame subtitle, and "else" just use the following code (which does not leave the space)?

```
  \begin{center}
    {\fontsize{14}{15}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries\insertframetitle}
  \end{center}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the subtitle is present or not:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
        subtitle is empty
      \else
        subtitle exists
      \fi%
}
```

---

That being said, did you check if you can't simply use the centred version of the default frametitle

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
```

?

Or if this does not exactly meets your requirements, use its definition and tweaks things from there? This way you would still be compatible with the usual beamer mechanisms to set fonts and colours.

Comment: I thought that beamer formatted the text first and the title later, so that there was no way to compute the available space.

Comment: @JohnKormylo The title is placed above the text and pushes it down. It is not necessary to compute the height because the rest of the space is filled with vfills (depending on the alignment) and the height is taken out from this flexible spaceing

Comment: Right, it still has to store the title argument first, which is what you are checking.